# DynamoDB Local - missing tables when starting with bash alias

Tags: bash, dynamo-local

I've installed DynamoDB locally on my Mac (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) and I've written a bash alias intending to avoid having to `cd` into the DynamoDB directory and run

`$ java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

every time I want to start the database.  However, the alias doesn't seem to be working as expected...

First off, the alias that I've written is

`alias ddb-start="java -Djava.library.path=~/Documents/dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar ~/Documents/dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb"`

and when I run `$ ddb-start`, the database starts as expected:

```
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:   false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:   true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *
```

The problem is, unless I run the script from `~/Documents/dynamodb/`, all of my tables are missing.

So if I `cd` to `Documents/dynamodb/` and then run `$ ddb-start`, everything is perfect. But if I open a new terminal window and run `$ ddb-start` (or run it from anywhere other than `Documents/dynamodb/`), Dynamo appears to start up as it should but when I list the tables in the JavaScript Shell, there are no tables.

I was hoping to be able to run the alias from any directory and have Dynamo start and run correctly.  Must I `cd` into the directory, even with an alias?  Or is there something wrong with the alias that I've written?

*** Ah, I've noticed that, whatever directory I run it from, a copy of `shared-local-instance.db` is created in that directory. I don't want that to happen, I want it to point at the 'original' `shared-local-instance.db` in `~/Documents/dynamodb/`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I was missing the `-dbPath` option in my alias. To run the alias from anywhere, I needed to specify where the shared db is located. The working alias is:

`alias ddb-start="java -Djava.library.path=~/Documents/dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar ~/Documents/dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ~/Documents/dynamodb/"`